# how to convert numpy.ndarray object to theano.tensor?

Tags: python, theano

I have a csv file to change to thenao.tensor, and I plan to do it via 2 steps
1 csv to ndarray: easy by using **genfromtxt** method.
2 ndarray to theano.tensor: how to do this step? Is there any sample code?

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_shared`, apparently: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#converting-from-python-objects

```
from theano.tensor import _shared
import numpy as np
x = _shared(np.arange(10))
```